# Validating number with dashes angularjs

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

Hi I have an input field where I want to do validation such that input only has numbers but with dashes and 11 number maximum

```
  i.e  1233-224-1234
```

I have following validation applied that only accepts numbers

```
  <input ng-pattern="customNum" ng-model=value.id />
   In my controller I have 

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.customNum = /^\d+$/;
}
```

Please let me know how i can update this so that 13 digits are entered out of which 11 are numbers and two are dashes. 
Thanks

Comment: Change your pattern to `^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{4}$` ?

Comment: If you are looking for a phone number validation you can use `ng-pattern` with a regex. You can find examples of that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here :http://jsbin.com/talaz/1/

```
<form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>      

        <input type="text" ng-model="code" name="code" ng-pattern='/^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/'    />Code :{{code}}<br />        
        <span ng-show="form.size.$error.pattern ">
          The code need to falow that 1234-123-1234 pattern</span>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if the digits are not fixed:

```
^\d+[-]\d+[-]\d+$
```

If your digits are fixed then :

```
^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reusable validation that you can use in a lot of places and change in one place you can use a custom validator directive. I've called it a creditcard validator just for the example.

```
<form name="form">
   <input type="text" ng-model="user.creditcard" name="creditcardNumber" validate-creditcard>
   <span ng-show="form.creditcardNumber.$error.creditcard">
      This is not a valid credit card number.
   </span>
</form>
```

```
 app.directive('validateCreditcard', function() {
      var creditcardRegex = /^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;

      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, el, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(input) {
            var valid = creditcardRegex.test(input);
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('creditcard', valid);
            return valid;
          }); 
        }
      };
    });
```

[example on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhJUx3s24gaxeLH8axGo?p=preview)